# How to create a Postgres trigger to ensure field is non-updateable

Tags: postgresql, trigger

I'm trying to create a Postgres trigger to ensure after a column's value has been set, it cannot be updated (basically make it readonly). So far I've come up with the following draft trigger.

1) First, am I on the correct track?
2) Is there value in returning `NEW`?
3) Must I preface `original_id` with `NEW.`?

```
CREATE FUNCTION check_id_change() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
    BEGIN
        IF OLD.original_id <> NEW.original_id THEN
            RAISE EXCEPTION 'cannot change original_id'; 
        END IF;
        RETURN NEW;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER client_update_trigger AFTER UPDATE ON client FOR EACH ROW
      EXECUTE PROCEDURE check_id_change();
```

Comment: You must be aware that this can be circumvented by operations that disable the trigger (temporarily) - only allowed for superusers or the owner.

Comment: Hmm.. interesting.. what operation is that? In another case, I have an audit trigger (copies OLD data to another table), and I've wondered how could I temporarily disable the trigger, in case, say... I need to fix data error without is copying OLD to the audit table (which wouldn't be correct since it wasn't the "current_user" who made the update).

Comment: `ALTER TABLE tbl DISABLE TRIGGER client_update_trigger | user | ALL;` Here is an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11086761/how-to-speed-up-a-slow-update-query/11088702#11088702

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a `before update` trigger.

Do you want to raise an exception or just have it silently not change the value?

Yes, you should return `NEW`.

Yes, you should prefix the column name with `NEW` or `OLD`.

You can use this if you don't want to raise an exception:

```
create function check_id_change() returns trigger language plpgsql as $$
begin

  new.original_id = old.original_id;

  return new;

end $$;
```

Comment: Ahh! I can't believe I had `AFTER UPDATE`! Thanks for your help... It would be more desirable to throw an error because at the app layer, it shouldn't attempt to update the column anyway. Also, I imagine the error will cause a transaction failure.

Answer (score 15):

Create a `BEFORE UPDATE` on your specific column `original_id`.
NOTE since the application which is using the DB should be aware of its constraints, therefore it is better to raise an exception when the column is getting updated, in order to notify the application layer of a failure, instead of just ignoring the update.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_id_change()
  RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
  IF NEW."original_id" IS DISTINCT FROM OLD."original_id"
  THEN
    RAISE EXCEPTION '"original_id" column cannot get updated';
  END IF;

  RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;

CREATE TRIGGER client_update_trigger
BEFORE UPDATE OF "original_id"
  ON "client"
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE check_id_change();
```

Or using [`WHEN` condition](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-createtrigger.html)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_id_change()
  RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
  RAISE EXCEPTION '"original_id" column cannot get updated';
END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;

CREATE TRIGGER client_update_trigger
BEFORE UPDATE OF "original_id"
  ON "client"
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (NEW."original_id" IS DISTINCT FROM OLD."original_id")
EXECUTE PROCEDURE check_id_change();
```

NOTE use [`IS DISTINCT FROM` comparison](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-comparison.html) instead of `<>` or `!=` unless the column has `NOT NULL` or you're sure that it's value will never be `NULL`.